# How to return a list from a method in C#

Tags: c#, linq, list

How can I return a list that contains the result of a LINQ to SQLquery? I'm trying this implementation, but I got this error.

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>'` to
>   `'System.Collections.Generic.List<object>`

Any help would be appreciated.

```
public List<Object> getShoes() 
{
    var query = from b in db.BrandTbls.AsQueryable()
                join m in db.ShoeModelTbls on b.BrandID equals m.BrandID 
                join s in db.ShoeTbls on m.ModelID equals s.ModelID 
                join i in db.ShoeImageTbls on s.ShoeID equals i.ShoeID 
                select new { s.ShoeID, s.Size, s.PrimaryColor, s.SecondaryColor, s.Quantity, m.ModelName, m.Price, b.BrandName, i.ImagePath };

    return query.ToList();
}
```

Comment: You can do `return query.Select(t => (object)t).ToList();`.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov Then it'll compile, but the users of this method won't be able to use it effectively.

Comment: For reference... check this [old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6830406/982431) too...

Comment: You could also change the method signature to `public IList getShoes()`, but as @Servy said, using the results would be awkward - you would have to use [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) (or reflection) to access the properties.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Anonymous types are specifically designed to be used entirely within the scope in which they are defined.  If you want to return the results of the query out from this method, you should create a new named type to represent the results of your query and select instances of that named type, not instances of an anonymous type.

Answer (score 3):

You can't return a List where T is an anonymous type; you need to return a known type. You can create a class

```
public class MyResult
{
    public string ShoeID {get; set;}
    public string Size {get; set;}
    public string PrimaryColor {get; set;}
    public string SecondaryColor {get; set;}
    public string Quantity {get; set;}
    public string ModelName {get; set;}
    public string Price {get; set;}
    public string BrandName {get; set;}
    public string ImagePath {get; set;}
}
```

then change your select like so

```
select new MyResult { ShoeID = s.ShoeID, Size = s.Size, PrimaryColor = s.PrimaryColor ........ };
```

and your method signature would change to

```
public List<MyResult> getShoes()
```

Comment: +1. To be very precise you actually can return "List where T is an anonymous type", but one need to pass such anonymous type outside of the method too. `List<T> MyMethod<T>(T fake){ return Enumerable.Repeat(new {Field1:100}, 10).ToLsit();} ... var list = MyMethod(new {Field1=42})`